# Customizing Android's default contacts app

Tags: android, contacts, customization

Is it possible to customize the Android's default Contacts app to display additional data???

I want to display the countries of the contacts along with their names. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

yes you can customise the default app of contacts and start your customised app using broadcasterreciever .

you can get source code of android default contacts app to customise

Comment: Tks for the reply... But the thing is, I do not want to create a custom app, I just want to display an additional field in the native app. Is it possible to do that?